# Android Wear + Webservice Calls

Tags: android, web-services, wear-os, okhttp, android-wear-data-api

I am trying to use OkHttp with Android Wear App.
All the Internet and required permissions are there.

As of goggling, I found that we can't communicate Web-service directly from the App ? We'll have to use Message and Data Api to pass the Data from Device to wear ?

Any other way for Webservice calling ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Android Wear doesn't require direct Internet connectivity, this is unfortunately not possible. There are a few devices that has WiFi, but there is no good way of filtering that in Google Play for now. Your best option is exactly what you described, perform the web service call from the application on your handset and deliver the result using the Data API to your Android Wear application.

Comment: One small comment: when you want to send back the result of your web service call to your watch from phone, don't use Data Api; there is no reason to sync the result across all devices, instead it is better to use the MessageApi to target the originating device.